# SQL Server : function to trim only leading zero's

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I have to make a function that trims leading zero's. It's however a little more complex than just getting rid of the first zero's.

Few examples and results:

- QZ0106 should become: QZ106
- 0108 should become: 108
- 00000B0108 should become: B0108
- 011B%000407A0001! should become: 11B%000407A0001!

I have built a query myself and came up with the following

```
 RETURN LEFT(@input, PATINDEX('%0%', @input)-1) + 
 SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@input, PATINDEX('%0%',@input), LEN(@input)), PATINDEX('%[^0]%', SUBSTRING(@input,PATINDEX('%0%',@input),LEN(@input))),len(@input))
```

Now, this works really good to get the above results.

**However:**

ZBET108 should stay **ZBET108.** - the above query returns **ZBET18**

I can't get it to work. The query should find the first numeric string and trim the leading zero's of that. What it seems to do now is search for the first zero and remove it.

Could anyone assist me in this?

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: I would suggest that you use a `WHILE` loop.  While there might be a way to accomplish this with string matching, the `WHILE` is probably the fastest path to working code.

Comment: What do you want to do if the only digit in the whole string is a single zero?

Comment: @SteveLovell then the zero should just stay and not be trimmed. This seems to work well in Gordon Linoff's query. However, ZBET000000 should become ZBET0. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this might work:

```
RETURN (CASE WHEN LEFT(@input, CHARINDEX('0', @input)-1) LIKE '%[0-9]%'
             THEN @input
             ELSE LEFT(@input, CHARINDEX('0', @input)-1) + 
 SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@input, PATINDEX('%0%',@input), LEN(@input)), PATINDEX('%[^0]%', SUBSTRING(@input,PATINDEX('%0%',@input),LEN(@input))),len(@input))
        END)
```

This just checks that the first 0 is the first digit in the string.

Comment: Thanks alot, this works great indeed!

Is there any way to add the following to this:

ZBET000000 should become ZBET0. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I've added the following to the WHEN statement:

WHEN @input LIKE '%0%' THEN replace(rtrim(replace(convert(char,@input),'0',' ')),' ',0) + '0'

This works fine but messes with the other ones such as '00000A0106000' --Result: 'A0106000' where it should be: A0106

Comment: @ocaj90 . . . I think you want `@input like '%[^0-9]0%' and @input not like '%[^0-9]0%[^0]%'`.